# IIS routing question

Tags: iis, iis-7, routes

I am having trouble reaching a site running under IIS as I'd expect.

The site is configured to listen on two bindings.  One listens to port 80 with host 'build', one listens to port 8090.  Both listen to any IP address.

From that machine, I can access the site through both bindings (http://build/ and http://192.168.0.4:8090).  From the remote machine, I can only access it through http://192.168.0.4:8090.

Both machines have an entry in their hosts file indicating that build is at 192.168.0.4.

The host's firewall has TCP open for ports 80 and 8090 .

The machine hosting the site also has a site listening on port 80 for any hostname.  This could be the problem, I am not sure.  Its not a problem when listening on the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Use Microsoft Network Monitor or Wireshark to capture the HTTP packets, and then they should tell you what happens under the hood. Only in this way, you can have a better understanding of how routing works.